# How to alter url property from persistence.xml when starts the server

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

i have an application Java + Jersey + Hibernate. Have too an .ini file, i want to get this access url to database when i start the server. I tried one option, but it makes persistence.xml alter every requisition and turns all of them extremely slow. The slow solution is:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
  String url = "jdbc:firebirdsql:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/3040:c:\\database\\database.FDB";


EntityManager em = null;
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);

try {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aplication", properties);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return em = (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
```

}

Is there another way to alter persistence.xml url to database one time and no more? I need a performer solution, dont want very slow solutions.

NOTE: The motive i need this is because i have a configuration application in phyton who alters the ini file for each new customer. My application in Java reads this ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the `EntityManagerFactory` a single time and cache it.
Here you create it at each time you create an `EntityManager` instance.

You could create the `EntityManagerFactory` in a listener or hook method that is invoked as your application is started and fully initialized :

```
private static EntityManagerFactory emf; // share emf

public void init() {       
    String url = "jdbc:firebirdsql:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/3040:c:\\database\\database.FDB";                       
    Map properties = new HashMap();
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);

    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aplication", properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then use the cached `EntityManagerFactory` in `getEntityManager()` :

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {       
   return (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
}
```